# Find pair of record from one table on the basis of point

Tags: php, mysql

I need a query or Algo. whatever best for my problem in mysql.

I have users table named

> users {id, points, gender, photo}

and

pointgiven table which has

> {id, // primary key
>
> compare_by_user_id, // user who selecting best user
>
> compare_user1, // user1 compare with user2
>
> compare_user2, // user2 compare with user1
>
> selected_user_by_me // answer between compareUser1 or compareuser2
>
> }

I want to fetch pair of two records from users table which has below conditions.

1. paired user points difference must not grater than 1000. for example user1=256 points, user2= 2000 points, and user3=1222 points so the correct pair is user1 and user3.
2. same pair will not come again if user compare any pair.

### Please help me to build this logic i am using php and mysql.

I tried this query where user_id 1 is logged in user and he is Male.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `users` 
 WHERE gender = 'Female' 
   AND id NOT IN (SELECT compare_user1 
                    FROM pointgiven 
                   WHERE user_id=1)  
   AND id NOT IN (SELECT compare_user2 
                    FROM pointgiven 
                   WHERE user_id=1)  
 ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?
also your 2nd condition required for you to mark results in the database as previously requested. so this would probably require another field.

Comment: for second condition i have one another table as listed above named "pointgiven".

Comment: Can you provide us with some data and the expected result on that data? http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be really nice as well. Also show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

i'm a little confused about the purpose of the 2nd table. if it's just for comparisons and your data set is not extremely large, you should be able to get the info like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users us1 
LEFT JOIN users us2 ON us1.id<>us2.id AND ABS(us1.points-us2.points)<=1000
GROUP BY IF(us1.id<us2.id,CONCAT(us2.id,':',us1.id),CONCAT(us1.id,':',us2.id)) /*one of many ways to avoid duplicates here */
ORDER BY us1.id
```